# Update text outside of partialview .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0

I have created a table from a list of objects, using a partialview. Using an ajax call(so the page doesnt have to refresh), when a user searchs, filters, etc, it updates the entries in the table(partialview) using a controller method.

Outside of the partial view, above the table, there is a "TotalHours" field that shows the total hours of the labor entries that are currently displayed in said table.

I was originally using a TempData variable in the controller method to update the "TotalHours" field each time a filter or search was applied, but for some reason, the table didnt refresh with search/filtered entires. If I remove the TempData variable, the search/filter function I created works perfectly.

My question is, what do I need to do to update the "TotalHours" field that is outside the partialview that is being refreshed? It is calculated by sum of "Hours" variables in the list of objects that are used in the table.

Controller code, with the TempData variable still included even though it doesnt update the partialview in the view:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<PartialViewResult> GetRows(Guid? cust, Guid? task, int? workType, int? weekFrom, int? weekTo, int? yearFrom, int? yearTo,
            string startDate = "", string endDate = "", string search = "",string sortName = "", string sortDir = "")
        {
            var model = new List<TimeEntryViewModel>();
            try
            {
                var timeRepo = new TimeRepository(_context);
                var customerRepo = new CustomerRepository(_context);
                var taskRepo = new TaskRepository(_context);
                var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
                var entries = await timeRepo.GetTimeEntriesByUserID(user.Id);
                DateTime startWeekYearDate;
                DateTime endWeekYearDate;
                int?[] weekYears = { weekFrom, weekTo, yearFrom, yearTo };

                var entriesFiltered = entries.Where(r => r.CustomerID == cust || cust.Equals(Guid.Empty) || cust == null)
                    .Where(r => r.TaskID == task || cust.Equals(Guid.Empty) || task == null)
                    .Where(r => r.WorkTypeID == workType || workType == null || workType == 0)
                    .ToList();

                if (weekYears.All(x => x.HasValue)) 
                {
                    startWeekYearDate = new DateTime((int)yearFrom, 1, 1);
                    endWeekYearDate = new DateTime((int)yearTo, 1, 1);
                    startWeekYearDate = startWeekYearDate.AddDays(7 * (int)weekFrom).AddDays(-7);
                    endWeekYearDate = endWeekYearDate.AddDays(7 * (int)weekTo);

                    entriesFiltered = entriesFiltered.Where(r => r.Start >= startWeekYearDate)
                        .Where(r => r.End <= endWeekYearDate).ToList();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate))
                {
                    entriesFiltered = entriesFiltered.Where(r => r.Start >= DateTime.Parse(startDate)).ToList();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate))
                {
                    entriesFiltered = entriesFiltered.Where(r => r.End <= DateTime.Parse(endDate)).ToList();
                }

                foreach (var entry in entriesFiltered)
                {
                    var entryVm = _mapper.Map<TimeEntryViewModel>(entry);

                    var customer = await customerRepo.GetCustomerByID(entry.CustomerID);
                    var task1 = await taskRepo.GetTaskById(entry.TaskID);
                    entryVm.Customer = customer;
                    entryVm.Task = task1;
                    entryVm.EmployeeName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
                    entryVm.CustomerName = customer.CustomerName;
                    entryVm.TaskName = task1.Name;

                    model.Add(entryVm);
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
                {
                    model = model.Where(r => r.EmployeeName.Contains(search)
                    || r.CustomerName.Contains(search) || r.TaskName.Contains(search)).ToList();
                }

                model = TimeEntryViewModel.SortList(model, sortName, sortDir);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e.Message, e);
            }
            var totalHours = 0.0;
            foreach(var m in model)
            {
                totalHours += m.TotalHours;
            }
            TempData["Total"] = Math.Round(totalHours, 2);


            return PartialView("_entryRows", model);
        }
```

PartialView cshtml:

```
@using TimeLogger.Core.Enums
@using TimeLogger.ViewModels
@model List<TimeEntryViewModel>

    @foreach(var entry in Model)
            {
                <tr class="customRow">
                    
                    <td>@entry.EmployeeName</td>
                    <td>@entry.Start</td>
                    <td>@entry.End</td>
                    <td>@entry.TotalHours</td>
                    <td>@entry.CustomerName</td>
                    <td>@entry.TaskName</td>
                    <td>@Enum.GetName(typeof(WorkType), entry.WorkTypeID)</td>
                    <td class="text-end">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        @*<i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical">
                        </i>*@
                        </button>
                        
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropDownMenu">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item editEntry"  data-id="@entry.Id">Edit</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item deleteEntry"  data-id="@entry.Id">Delete</a>
                            
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

View that renders partialview:

```
@using TimeLogger.Core.Enums
@using TimeLogger.ViewModels
@model List<TimeEntryViewModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Time Entries";
}


<div id='modal-placeholder' class='modal'>  
    <div class="modal-dialog">  
        <div class="modal-content">  
            <div id='modal-placeholderContent'></div>  
        </div>  
    </div> 
</div>   
<div class="entries">
    <div class="container mt-5 px-2">
    
        <div class="mb-2 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        
                <div class="position-relative">
                    <span class="position-absolute search"><i id="search" class="fa fa-search modal-custom"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control w-100" placeholder="" id="searchBox">
                </div>
        <div class="position-relative">
                    <span id="totalHours" class="totalHours">Total Hours: @TempData["Total"]</span>
                </div>
            
            <div class="px-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary addEntry">Add Entry &nbsp;<i  style="font-size: 1.25rem" class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2"></i></button>
                <button class="btn filter" onclick="toggleDiv('filters'); return false">Filters &nbsp;<i id="arrow" style="font-size: 1.25rem" class="fa fa-angle-down text-gray-dark bg-light-grey fa-2x"></i></button>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="filters" style="display:none">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm text-white">
                    Customer: @Html.DropDownList("Customers", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Customers, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "customerDropDown" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm text-white">
                    Task: @Html.DropDownList("Tasks", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Tasks, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "tasksDropDown" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm text-white">
                    Work Type: @Html.DropDownList("WorkTypes", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.WorkTypes, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "workTypesDropDown" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="weeksYears">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm text-white">
                        From Week: @Html.DropDownList("WeekFrom", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Weeks, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "weekFromDropDown" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm text-white">
                        To Week: @Html.DropDownList("WeekTo", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Weeks, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "weekToDropDown" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm text-white">
                        From Year: @Html.DropDownList("YearFrom", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Years, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "yearFromDropDown" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm text-white">
                        To Year: @Html.DropDownList("YearTo", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Years, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "yearToDropDown" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="dates" style="display: none;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm text-white">
                        <div id="date-picker1" class="md-form md-outline input-with-post-icon datepicker">
                          <label for="startDateFilter">Start Date</label>
                          <i class="fas fa-calendar input-prefix"></i>
                          <input placeholder="Select date" type="text" id="startDateFilter" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm text-white">
                        <div id="date-picker2" class="md-form md-outline input-with-post-icon datepicker">
                            <label for="startDateFilter">End Date</label>
                          <i class="fas fa-calendar input-prefix"></i>
                          <input placeholder="Select date" type="text" id="endDateFilter" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm text-white">
                    <button onclick="filter(); return false" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
                    <button id="dateWeeksToggle" onclick="toggleDatesWeeks(); return false" class="btn btn-info">Filters for Dates</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm text-white">
                    <button onclick="clearFilter(); return false" type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Clear Filters</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
    
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-borderless">
                <thead>
                    <tr id="sort-row" class="bg-light">
                        <th id="e" order="desc">Employee</th>
                        <th id="st" order="desc">Start Time</th>
                        <th id="et" order="desc">End Time</th>
                        <th id="h" order="desc">Hours</th>
                        <th id="c" order="desc">Customer</th>
                        <th id="t" order="desc">Task</th>
                        <th id="wt" order="desc">Work Type</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="searchFilterResult">
                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_entryRows", Model)
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy option that comes to mind would be to add a hidden input to your partial view and set it's value to the Total Count of `TempData`, then in your ajax use this hidden value to set the one outside of your partial view:

**Partial View**:

```
....
<input type="hidden" id="hdnhourlytotal" value="@(TempData["total"] ?? 0)" />
@foreach(var entry in Model)
....
```

**ajax**:

```
success: function(data) {
   //add view to DOM
  ....
  //set the element outside of your partial using hidden input
  const totalfromhidden = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hdnhourlytotal").value);
  document.getElementById("totalHours").textContent = `Total Hours: ${totalfromhidden}`;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure why I didnt think of this myself. This is simple, effective way to fix the problem!

Comment: Forgot to add though. you are saying to ParseInt when the number needs to be a decimal, so ParseFloat is what I am using.

Comment: @TThomas07 Updated to `parseFloat`